# Google Apps "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]" Error with JSON API

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have some JSON data that I need to access via my google apps script. On the same script I have been able to access other parts of JSON data from the same API. For this I have used the code before or a variation of it as the JSON data is displayed slightly differently in each case. However the data I am trying to get now is not being applied to the Google Sheet and instead renders this error:

> Cannot convert Array to Object[][].

```
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  var dataSet = dataAll;


  var rows = [],
      data;


  for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataSet).length; i++) { data = dataSet[Object.keys(dataSet)[i]]; rows.push(data.duration);        }


  dataRange = sheet.getRange(24, 2, rows.length, 2); 
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
```

The JSON data I am trying to get is displayed as follows:

```
{
    chats: [
    {    type: "XXX",
    oneone: "XXX",
    twotwo: [ ],
    number: "two",
    one: "XXXX",
    two: "XXXX",
    three: 
{
    oneone: "XXX",
    twotwo: "XXX",
    three: "XXX",
    fourfour: "XXX",
    five: "XXX",
    six: "XXX",
    seven: "XXX",
    eight: "XXX"
    },
    ten: [
    {
    tenten: "XXX",
    nine: "XXX"
    }
    ],
    test: [ ],
    tester: "XXX",
    duration: XXX,     
}
```

I need to access the '`duration`' data but cannot seem to get this to work without getting the error. Any help is appreciated. The above JSON data has been edited to show alternative values and variables as the information in private. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to write an array that looks like this:
`[1,2,3,4,5]`

GAS' `setValues()` function requires and Array of Arrays with equal length, the sub arrays being rows and the elements in those sub arrays the cells from left to right in that row.

If you want to write the data in rows you need to add the values to the array like so:

```
rows.push([data.duration])
```

And if you want to write them all in one row but separate columns you need to:

```
 var rows = [[]];
 ...
 rows[0].push(data.duration);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is returning 3 pieces of data that all say undefined. Any ideas?